# How to create Function on Python to return a dict() from a string?

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I want create a function which receve a string (str) with data from a txt file and return the dict like that:

```
values = {'first' : 43, 'second': 42, ....}
```

but my code prints

```
{'first': '43'}
{'second': '42'}
{.....}
```

I used Print() ..

```
openfile = open('file.txt', 'r')
for lines in openfile :
dataf = lines.split('-')
dictionary = {}
dictionary[dataf[0] = dataf[1]
print(dictionary)
```

I did it, but it isn't what I want.

can someone help me with this?

thanks

Comment: `print(values)`

Comment: I did it. but I want read the file, and this functions returns the dict

Comment: You should post a sample of your data file (the first few lines)

Comment: Ok, I edited the ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is you are creating a new dictionary in each iteration overwriting the previous one.
The code should be as follows:

```
openfile = open('file.txt', 'r')
dictionary = {}                      #dictionary is created here
for lines in openfile :
  dataf = lines.split('-')
  dictionary[dataf[0]] = dataf[1]    #inserting into same dict
print(dictionary)                    #print the dict after inserting everything
```

I hope this answers your question!